# Check if an array includes some objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

As shown below, if I would like to find whether an object in testArray is in the currentArray, I can use for loop to traverse arrays, or I can use `find()`, `some()`, `include()`. The worst performance is if I go all fall into at least once O(n^2).

If I firstly filter the items in currentArray which the balance is not 999 or 999.999 and then to check testArray. Does the performance be better than fall into at least once? Or is there any way that doing better?

Thanks!

```js
let currentArray = [
  {account: 1, balance: 200},
  {account: 2, balance: 100},
  {account: 3, balance: 300},
  {account: 4, balance: 999},
  {account: 5, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 6, balance: 999},
  {account: 15, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 8, balance: 100},
  {account: 9, balance: 300},
  {account: 10, balance: 300},
]

let testArray = [
  {account: 4, balance: 999},
  {account: 5, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 6, balance: 999},
  {account: 7, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 8, balance: 999},
  {account: 9, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 10, balance: 999},
  {account: 11, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 12, balance: 999},
  {account: 13, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 14, balance: 999},
  {account: 15, balance: 999.999},
]
```

Comment: do you want to filter base an the account or the balance ?

Comment: _"Does the performance be better than fall into at least once?"_ - Test it. With the given example this is yet another case of premature optimization. In the worst case you would need 120 comparisons... A matter of some milliseconds.

Comment: [Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Given the account ids are unique, just use a data structure indexed by them (e.g. a `Map`) and you're back to linear time complexity.

Comment: Performance and time complexity are different concepts. I'd change "performance" to "time complexity" in your post. As Andreas says, if your arrays are always small there's no benefit to trying to reduce time complexity.

Comment: Is `account` unique, or can there be multiple objects in one array that have the same `account`?

Comment: @trincot both are possible, which can be unique or multiple object in one array.

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the example?

Comment: @trincot sorry, I did not check the comment yesterday. Yes, the expected output is like what your feedback shows below. I'll practice it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you expect the following result for the given example arrays:

```
[
    { "account":  4, "balance": 999     },
    { "account":  5, "balance": 999.999 },
    { "account":  6, "balance": 999     },
    { "account": 15, "balance": 999.999 }
]
```

...as these occur in both arrays.

To achieve that with a better time complexity, use a unique key for each object. Knowing that your objects have a key that consists of two properties, you can combine those two values in an array and produce its JSON encoding (or any other suitable encoding): that string will be a unique id for each object. Store those of the first array in a set, and then iterate the second array to check if the object has such an identifier that occurs in the set.

```js
let currentArray = [
  {account: 1, balance: 200},
  {account: 2, balance: 100},
  {account: 3, balance: 300},
  {account: 4, balance: 999},
  {account: 5, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 6, balance: 999},
  {account: 15, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 8, balance: 100},
  {account: 9, balance: 300},
  {account: 10, balance: 300},
];

let testArray = [
  {account: 4, balance: 999},
  {account: 5, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 6, balance: 999},
  {account: 7, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 8, balance: 999},
  {account: 9, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 10, balance: 999},
  {account: 11, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 12, balance: 999},
  {account: 13, balance: 999.999},
  {account: 14, balance: 999},
  {account: 15, balance: 999.999},
];

const hash = ({account, balance}) => JSON.stringify([account, balance]);

let ref = new Set(currentArray.map(hash));
let result = testArray.filter(obj => ref.has(hash(obj)));
console.log(result);
```

If you are only interested *whether* there is such an object, then use `some` instead of `filter`. The return value will be a boolean: true when there is such an object, and false otherwise.

If you are interested to find *one* such object, then use `find` instead of `filter`. The return value will be the first found object, or `undefined` when there is no such object.

The key to the better time complexity is the use of the `Set`. It could also be a plain object with the JSON strings as property names, and for each an arbitrary value (like `true`).